# Unvoting closing question

Tags: support, vote-to-close, undo

I've marked question as duplicate. But then I understand that it is not total duplicate but I can't revote, I can't remove my vote

Comment: I don't vote yet so I don't really know how it works, but can't you contact a mod and ask to remove the vote?

Comment: It is not a big deal to interupt moderator

Comment: We already saw it, dismissed it as invalid, and made a rude comment to ourselves about what a stupid flag it was.

Comment: Good rude news, Will! Have a good day :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do have faced this problem for few times, however it seems that for closing a question, you will need **4 more users** to agree to your vote anyway. So this should not be a real issue since you have voted it to be closed as duplicate but if the question does not get 4 more votes, it will still stay open meaning your vote will be void.

Comment: Anyway it looks strange for topic author that somebody wants to close it but he fon't know why. It is confusing me and it is confusing topicaster

Comment: @f100r - That other user will see that there is one close vote for duplicate. When that other user sees the duplicate link, he will understand that this is not exactly duplicate and hence he wont proceed. He will cancel his vote.

Comment: @fl00r: Then leave a comment saying as much.  I do it from time to time: I'll make an irreversible mistake and then apologize in the comments.

Comment: Also keep in mind that all close votes expire after some time, 48 hours as far as I remember..

Comment: From [close-vote-privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions) _Close votes age away harmlessly after 4 days if the threshold is not reached_